# VS Code - Git "Please enter the commit message for your changes". I do, I can't get it to to commit

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

I had a complex merge that ended up in Visual Studio Code's output that starts with this:

> Please enter the commit message for your changes. Lines starting with
> '#' will be ignored, and an empty message aborts the commit. On branch
> master Your branch and 'origin/master' have diverged, and have 12 and
> 27 different commits each, respectively. (use "git pull" to merge the
> remote branch into yours)

This is a remote branch being merged to master, so I can't merge "the remote branch into yours", I already am).

No matter what I do to modify this file, it won't commit.  I notice in the VS Code output that it just seems to loop?

[image: Example]

I've seen examples of how to easily get around this in editors like Vim but this is VS Code, and have not seen any answers.

Comment: What happens when you save the file, and then close it?

Comment: You can always just use the Git CLI in the Terminal in VSCode. There's no need to actually use VSCode's Git integration...

Comment: @joanis I'm well aware.  I'm just curious if this was a bug in VS Code or of I'm doing something wrong.